# Golang assignment

Tags: for-loop, go

We want to calculate a sum of squares of some integers, excepting negatives
The first line of the input will be an integer N (1 <= N <= 100)
Each of the following N test cases consists of one line containing an integer X (0 < X <= 100), followed by X integers (Yn, -100 <= Yn <= 100) space-separated on the next line
For each test case, calculate the sum of squares of the integers excepting negatives, and print the calculated sum to the output. No blank line between test cases
(Take input from standard input, and output to standard output)
Do not use the for statement
Use only standard libraries
Write it in the Go programming language

Sample input

2

4

3 -1 1 14

5

9 6 -53 32 16

Sample Output

206

1397

So I am new to Golang , and I managed to solve this using for statements.
How can I abide by the given and not use for? using only standard libraries?
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var N int
    fmt.Scan(&N)
    for a := 0; a < N; a++ {
        var X int
        var res int = 0
        fmt.Scan(&X)
        for b := 0; b < X; b++ {
            var Y int
            fmt.Scan(&Y)
            if Y > 0 {
                res = res + Y*Y
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(res)
    }
}
```

// I used fmt to read data from console. Sum of squares is found out only if the number is positive. Then computed sum is displayed to the screen

I got the same output expected, but not using the required method

This is how I did it in Java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SumSquares {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = in.nextInt(), m, num;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < n) {
                int j = 0, sum = 0;
                m = in.nextInt();
                while (j < m) {
                    num = in.nextInt();
                    if (num > 0) {
                        sum += num*num;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                System.out.println(sum);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just replace `for` with a label, a `goto` and an `if` like the compiler does anyway and call it a day.

Comment: @GeorgesBatikha https://golang.org/ref/spec#Labeled_statements and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Goto_statements

Comment: I will give it a go- no pun intended , and will post my solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Go does not have the `while`, `until`, or `foreach` loop constructs you may be familiar with from other languages. In Go, the `for` and `range` statements replace them all:

```
// Three expressions, i.e. the usual
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
}

// Single expression; same as while(condition) in other languages
for condition { 
}

// No expressions; endless loop, i.e. same as while(true) or for(;;)
for {
}

// for with range; foreach and similar in other languages. Works with slices, maps, and channels.
for i, x := range []T{} {
}
```

If you are not allowed to use Go's single loop construct, you are left with either recursion or [the `goto` statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Goto_statements):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var N int
    fmt.Scan(&N)

    fmt.Println(f(N, 0))
}

func f(n, sum int) int {
    if n == 0 {
        return sum
    }

    var Y int
    fmt.Scan(&Y)
    if Y > 0 {
        sum += Y * Y
    }

    return f(n-1, sum)
}
```

With `goto`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var N, Y, sum int
    fmt.Scan(&N)

again:
    fmt.Scan(&Y)
    if Y > 0 {
        sum += Y * Y
    }

    N--
    if N > 0 {
        goto again
    }

    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

Comment: The question has apparently been edited. "Getting the sum of squares in Golang" is a bit terse to understand what the program is supposed to do. What is  the purpose of the instruction `fmt.Println(43)` in your goto code example ?

Comment: Probably an oversight. I removed it.

Comment: The `// for with range` line was gold.  It's the syntax for looping over an array literal, and has naught to do with the question, but gold, nonetheless.